# What is "her going mad" in "I am afraid of her going mad"?

Tags: phrases, clauses

I'm having moment. In the sentence

*"I am afraid of her going mad"*

***"her going mad"*** is the object/complement of the proposition "of".

But what is it?  It has an "-ing" verb form.  Surely it's not a finite clause, is it?  So is it an non-finite clause?  But if so, what type?  Gerund?  Participle?  "Her" is objective, but is it a subject?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of gerund-participial non-finite clause. [CAGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) explains that:

> In formal style the subject of a ***gerund-participial clause*** that is functioning as complement (of a verb or preposition) appears in genitive case, as in
>
> - She didn't approve of *[**his** being given a second chance]*. (p. 110)

**EDIT:** Thanks to the sharp eye of some users, I realised the confusion between *her* genitive and *her* accusative. CGEL helps us here too. On page 210 it gives this example:

> She insisted on [***my*** / ***me*** *being present throughout the interview*]. [here you could replace the pair my/me with his/him]

And it explains that:

> The clause between the brackets is *complement of the preposition* ***on***. If a personal pronoun subject is not in the genitive, then it takes accusative case... ***The choice between genitive and non-genitive depends partly on style and partly on the type of NP***. The ***genitive is characteristic of fairly formal style***, and overall it is relatively infrequent. It is most likely with personal pronouns, and next most likely with short singular NPs denoting humans.

The book goes on to enumerate cases in which genitive subjects are not possible, like in this example:

> She sought advice from Ed, [***he*** being the most experienced of her colleagues]

No genitive possible here, and the informal accusative *him* would sound out of place in this formal sentence.

So there you go, in you particular case

> She didn't approve of ***him*** being given a second chance.

is perfectly grammatical but less formal than

> She didn't approve of ***his*** being given a second chance.

Comment: Thank you!  You're the best.

Comment: Just a follow up question.  Is this grammatical:  _"She didn't approve of **him** being given a second chance."_

Comment: @femke_0 https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2625/when-is-a-gerund-supposed-to-be-preceded-by-a-possessive-adjective-determiner

Comment: @femke_0 Your follow up example is similar sentence with the example I quoted from CAGEL, so yes, it is grammatical. Thanks to our good mods, you can find more information at the link above, Thanks, AndrewL.

Comment: Thanks again to you both.

Comment: Fev Andrew Erm, @femke_0's example is different from the one quoted from CGEL. There the subject pronoun is in genitive case, but in Femke's one here it is accusative. It's not possible to tell whether *her* in OP's original question is accusative or genitive, of course, because the two forms are homophonous! [And thus your answer needs augmenting, @fev!]

Comment: Your example uses *her* / *her*; try swapping in *him* / *his* and go from there with your explanation.

Comment: To clarify, the intention in the OP was accusative (her/him).